# Interview Question - Find the Max difference of Two elements in the Array in less than O(n^2) - the Lower element should precede the Greater element

Tags: arrays, algorithm, maximum-profit-problem

During an interview, I've been asked the following Question:

> You're given an array of integer numbers.
>
> Find the **maximum difference** between two elements `arr[j] - arr[i]`
> for any sub array in the array, so that `j>i`.
>
> *For example:*
>
> array = `{20,18,45,78,3,65,55}`, max diff is `65 - 3 = 62`.
>
> array = `{20,8,45,78,3,65,55}`, max diff is `78 - 8 = 70`.

*Here is the solution I come up with:*

```
private static int calculateProfit() {
    int[] arr = {20, 18, 45, 78, 3, 65, 55};
    int maxProfit = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = arr.length - 1; j > 0; j--) {
            if (arr[i] < arr[j] && i < j) {
                maxProfit = Math.max(arr[j] - arr[i], maxProfit);
            }
        }
    }
    return maxProfit; // ans: (65 - 3) = 62 
}
```

The problem is that it runs in **O(n^2)**. How it can be done with a better time complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved in a linear time **O(n)**, with a single run through the given array.

We need to declare only a couple of local variables, no data additional data structures required, space complexity is **O(1)**.

These are the variables we need to track:

- `min` - the lowest value encountered so far;
- `max` - the highest encountered value;
- `maxProfit` - maximal profit that can be achieved at the moment.

While declaring these variables, we can either initialize `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, or initialize both with the value of the first element in the array (this element should be present because the array needs to have at least two elements, otherwise the task has no sense).

*And here is a couple of caveats:*

- Since `max` element **can not** precede the `min` element, when a new `min` element is encountered (when the *current element* is less than `min`) the `max` element also needs to be reinitialized (with `Integer.MIN_VALUE` or with the value of the *current element* depending on the strategy you've chosen at the beginning).
- `maxProfit` should be checked against the difference between `max` and `min` each time when a new `max` has been encountered.

That's how it might be implemented:

```
public static int calculateProfit(int[] arr) {
    
    if (arr.length < 2) return -1; // incorrect input
    
    int max = arr[0];
    int min = arr[0];
    int maxProfit = 0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        int next = arr[i];
        if (next > max) {
            max = next;
            maxProfit = Math.max(max - min, maxProfit);
        } else if (next < min){
            min = next;
            max = next;
        }
    }
    return maxProfit;
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(calculateProfit(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 10}));
    System.out.println(calculateProfit(new int[]{1, 10, -10, 4, 8}));
    System.out.println(calculateProfit(new int[]{5, 8, 12, 1, 9}));
    System.out.println(calculateProfit(new int[]{20, 18, 45, 78, 3, 65, 55}));
}
```

*Output:*

```
9     // [1, 2, 3, 4, 10]            ->    10 - 1 = 9
18    // [1, 10, -10, 4, 8]          -> 8 - (-10) = 18
8     // [5, 8, 12, 1, 9]            ->     9 - 1 = 8
62    // [20, 18, 45, 78, 3, 65, 55] ->    65 - 3 = 62
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Start by finding the first possible solution. This is easy. Scan left-to-right. Track *p* for the index of the lowest value seen so far.  As soon as you see a new non-descending value, set *q* to that index and goto `step 2`:

   ```
   [8, 5, 2, 2, 4, ...]
   [   D  D  -, I     ] # Look for first increasing value
   [      p     q     ] # arr[p] < arr[q] and p < q
   ```
2. Now continue looping over the array, looking for an improvement to the solution.  The new wrinkle is tracking a *u*, the index of a value smaller than `arr[p]` but is unused because it is to the right of *q*:

   ```
   [8, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, ...]
   [      p     q     u     ]  # arr[u] < arr[p] but u > q
   ```

For each new value in the loop, update the solution.  If the new i/u difference is bigger than the p/q solution, it becomes the new best:

```
   [8, 5, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 2, X, ...]
   [      p     q     u     i, ...]
          \...../                    Previous best solution
                      \-----/        Potential new best
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum profit at an arbitrary index `b` where we must use `b` as the rightmost element of the pair is `arr[b] - arr[a]` where `a` is the index from the subarray before `b` with the minimum value (i.e. `a` ranges from `0` to `b - 1`). Clearly, this minimum value can be maintained while iterating forwards through the array. Then, we can just try all indexes as the rightmost index and take the maximum of all those differences. There is no need to keep track of the maximum array value encountered so far at all.

```java
static int calculateProfit(int[] arr) {
    if (arr == null || arr.length < 2) return 0;
    int min = arr[0], maxProfit = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        maxProfit = Math.max(maxProfit, arr[i] - min);
        min = Math.min(min, arr[i]);
    }
    return maxProfit;
}
```

Comment: @greybeard Good point. I've updated `maxProfit` to start at `Integer.MIN_VALUE` which rectifies that. (None of the other answers handle this either.)

Comment: A pity to lose *foreach*, but I don't see how to use *foreach* without `long` state/arithmetic.